# Día siguiente hábil comparando con tabla de días inhábiles y que detecte sábado y domingo como inhábil también, en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo que realizar un stored procedure que detecte un día inhábil de una tabla (dias_inhabiles) y que también detecte Sábado y Domingo como inhábil y me regrese el siguiente día hábil.

Este procedimiento lo necesito para que actualice algunos campos de otra tabla a esa fecha hábil siguiente.

Tengo este código:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Actualiza] 
    @_dia_actual DATE
AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @_resp_consul INT = 0,
            @_contador INT = 0
            

    
    SET @_resp_consul = (SELECT COUNT(*) from dias_inhabiles WHERE fecha = @_dia_actual);
     
    IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @_dia_actual) = 7 OR DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @_dia_actual) = 1 -- SABADO
    BEGIN
    SET @_resp_consul = (SELECT COUNT(*) from dias_inhabiles WHERE fecha = @_dia_actual);

    WHILE @_resp_consul != 0
    BEGIN   

    SET @_dia_actual = DATEADD(DAY,@_contador,@_dia_actual)
       
    SET @_resp_consul = (SELECT COUNT(*) from dias_inhabiles WHERE fecha = @_dia_actual);

    IF @_resp_consul = 0
    BEGIN
    BREAK;
    END

    SET @_contador = @_contador+1

    END
    
    IF @_resp_consul > 0

    BEGIN
    IF @_resp_consul > 0 
    BEGIN
    SET @_resp_consul = (SELECT COUNT(*) from dias_inhabiles WHERE fecha = @_dia_actual);

    WHILE @_resp_consul != 0
    BEGIN   

    SET @_dia_actual = DATEADD(DAY,@_contador,@_dia_actual)
       
    SET @_resp_consul = (SELECT COUNT(*) from dias_inhabiles WHERE fecha = @_dia_actual);

    IF @_resp_consul = 0
    BEGIN
    BREAK;
    END

    SET @_contador = @_contador+1

    END
    END
    END
    END

    SELECT @_dia_actual AS RESULTADO

END
```

He leído en varias páginas y no logro encontrar la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se puede hacer de una forma más sencilla y con un solo llamado a tu tabla de días inhábiles.

Empezamos generando fechas a partir de la fecha enviada. Para eso podemos usar una tabla de números. Una tabla de números es una tabla con una sola columna de números consecutivos. Esta tabla nos ayuda a eliminar la necesidad de bucles. Los números los sumamos a la fecha que deseas y así generamos las posibles fechas. En esta ocasión, generé la tabla al vuelo con 36 filas, pero pueden ser menos.

```
DECLARE @Fecha  date = '20231223';

SELECT DATEADD( DD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, @Fecha) Fecha
FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))x(n)
CROSS JOIN(VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))y(n) --6x6 = 36 filas o fechas.
```

Obviamente, eso no nos sirve así. Pero necesitamos obtener la primer fila que no sea fin de semana ni esté en la tabla de días inhábiles. Así que vamos a agregar esas limitantes. Recuerda que los días de la semana dependen de la configuración de tu conexión. Por eso cambio la configuración a español porque mi servidor está configurado en inglés. Aquí agregué columnas de prueba para ver el día de la semana que corresponde a la fecha.

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish;

DECLARE @Fecha  date = '20231223';

WITH cteFechas AS(
    SELECT DATEADD( DD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, @Fecha) Fecha
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))x(n)
    CROSS JOIN(VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))y(n) --6x6 = 36 filas o fechas.
)
SELECT TOP 1 fecha, DATENAME(DW, fecha), DATEPART(DW, fecha)
FROM cteFechas
WHERE DATENAME(DW, fecha) NOT IN( 'Sábado', 'Domingo')
AND fecha NOT IN( SELECT fecha FROM dias_inhabiles)
ORDER BY Fecha;
```

Pero como eso es complejo para escribirlo en cada consulta, sería mejor convertirlo en una función.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SiguienteDiaHabil(
    @Fecha  date 
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH cteFechas AS(
    SELECT DATEADD( DD, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1, @Fecha) Fecha
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))x(n)
    CROSS JOIN(VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))y(n) --6x6 = 36 filas o fechas.
)
SELECT TOP 1 fecha
FROM cteFechas
WHERE DATENAME(DW, fecha) NOT IN( 'Sábado', 'Domingo')
AND fecha NOT IN( SELECT fecha FROM dias_inhabiles)
ORDER BY Fecha;

GO
```

Y se puede llamar de la siguiente forma para que lo uses al actualizar los datos.

```
UPDATE t SET
    fecha = dh.fecha
FROM Tabla t
CROSS APPLY dbo.SiguienteDiaHabil( t.fecha) dh
WHERE t.fecha <> dh.Fecha;
```